# Why App Engine running Rails app spins up Compute Engine instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am running Rails on the App Engine. My question is why Google is running the Compute Engine. I just want to run the App Engine. Google starts the App Engine and the Compute Engine when I deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine provides two environments - standard "sandboxed" environment and Managed VMs. Currently the standard environment supports only Java, Python, PHP and Go. If you want to use something else, you have to go with Managed VMs. In fact, Managed VMs are Google Compute Engine virtual machines.

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/).

Comment: So but ti's cheap right ? because the vm's don't need really power ?

Comment: Managed VMs are charged the cost of the underlying Google Compute Engine Virtual Machines. Check [GCE Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing).

Comment: No problem. If it helped, mark please the answer as accepted so that the others can benefit.